# How to let any users run .exe program that reads java methods from its c++ code?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Here the zip file of source code:
http://cfile218.uf.daum.net/attach/254F2D4F5211EF93107910

,or visible source code in the bottom.

I just compiled and ran it on my PC: worked fine in both debug and release mode.

However, if I try to run it on another PC (Windows XP is installed in), it shows an error saying that I do not have "jvm.dll" so it cannot run it.

Therefore I installed java from the address "http://java.com/en/download/index.jsp" and runned it. However, it still said same error.

It is my problem....

How would I make it be run on other normal PCs that has no JDK or MSVC? because normal users definitely do not own JDK..

```
## ================================ ##
// it is the c++ code that starts JVM and run java source code...

               #include <iostream>
              #include <windows.h>
             #include <jni.h>

       #pragma comment(lib, "jvm.lib")

       using namespace std;


       void main(){

    cout<<"JVM Create Start!!"<<endl;

    // JavaVM create & JVM environment setting start
    JavaVMOption options[1];
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JNIEnv *env;
    JavaVM *jvm;
    long status;

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.class.path=.";
    memset(&vm_args, 0, sizeof(vm_args));
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_6;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.options = options;
    status = JNI_CreateJavaVM(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    // JavaVM create & JVM environment setting end

    cout<<"JVM Operating......."<<endl;

    cout<<"\n10+20?\n"<<endl;

    jclass cls;
    jmethodID mid;
    jobject obj;
    int staticresult=0;
    int result=0;

    if(status != JNI_ERR)
    {
        cls = env->FindClass("FirstJavaEx");

        if(cls != 0)
        {
            //
            // Use the static method start
            //
            cout<<"\t'static'start calling method" << endl;
            mid = env->GetStaticMethodID(cls, "staticAdd", "(II)I");
            if (mid != 0)
            {
                staticresult = env->CallStaticIntMethod(cls, mid, 10, 20);
                cout<<"\t'static'result: " << staticresult << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("mid error\n");
                return;
            }
            //
            // Use the static method end
            //

            //
            //Create the Instance of InvokeFirstEX Class start
            //
            cout<<"\n\tInvokeFirstEx create instance" << endl;
            jmethodID cls_constructor = env->GetMethodID(cls, "<init>", "()V");

            if (cls_constructor != 0) {             
                obj = env->NewObject(cls, cls_constructor, "()V");
                cout<<"\t\tstart calling method" << endl;
                mid = env->GetMethodID(cls, "AddFunc", "(II)I"); 
                if (mid != 0)
                {
                    result = env->CallIntMethod(obj, mid, 10, 20);
                    cout<<"\t\tresult: " << result << endl;
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("mid error\n");
                    return;
                }
            }       
        }
        else 
        {
            printf("Can't find class\n");
            return;
        }

        jvm->DestroyJavaVM();
        cout<<"\nJVM Destroyed!!"<<endl;
    }

}


## ================================ ##
```

Comment: Sounds like a configuration problem - quite possibly that the installer didn't install "for all users". If you have admin rights on the machine, it's most likely just a case of moving some environment variables from the "per user" to "per system" settings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot load JVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15873213/cannot-load-jvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma comment(lib, "jvm.lib")
```

Because of this, your program is statically linked against `jvm.lib`. That means that the `jvm.dll` must be somewhere on the DLL search path (current directory, C:\Windows\System32, %PATH%, ...) when your application is started. Probably the `jvm.dll` is somewhere on your `%PATH%` and so the application works. But as you also noticed, it's usually not like that. So you have to use a different approach: Loading the library manually.

I have written a detailed explanation on that [**in another answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17349975/1590632). That should be exactly what you need, you just have to replace all the `throw gcnew System::ComponentModel::Win32Exception` with your own error handling, since you're not using C++/CLI.

Edit: Instead of `RegGetValue`, you could use `RegQueryValueEx`:

```
RegQueryValueEx(jKey, TEXT("CurrentVersion"), NULL, NULL, versionString, &bufsize);
```

But if you take a look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx) of that function, you'll see that you should add a null terminator:

```
if (bufsize <= (16 * sizeof TCHAR)) // or whatever the buffer size is
    versionString[bufsize] = TEXT('\0');
else // error: buffer overflow
```

Comment: Hello main-- I made it almost worked, but there were another error saying on Windows XP that "couldnt be able to find regGetValueA from ADVAPI32.dll". I searched it that Windows XP do not support regGetValueA method.. is there a replacement for those functions to make it run on Win xp? thx for helping me, your answers are great!

Comment: Is a part of your question still unanswered or why haven't you selected an answer?

Comment: opps I just did. maybe I have to select answered for all other questions right now.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I make it be run on other normal PCs that has no JDK or
>   MSVC? because normal users definitely do not own JDK..

They won't need JDK, installing JRE on clients is enough. But they definitely need a means to access jvm.dll (by adding its path to PATH environment varialble explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15877661/279982)).