# Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, lwjgl

I have a simple [LWJGL](http://lwjgl.org) java application. And if I try calling it using:

```
java -jar=LWJGL_Fullscreen.jar -Djava.library.path="M:\Java\SE\LWJGL_Fullscreen\final\lib\native\windows\"
```

i get the following error message:

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
```

but the path set using `-Djava.library.path` is correct. If i am using Netbeans and hit the run button the application starts and runs as expected.

how can i start this program from console?

**UDAPTE**

As suggested by david i have also tryed:

```
java -Djava.library.path="M:\Java\SE\LWJGL_Fullscreen\final\lib\native\windows\" -jar=LWJGL_Fullscreen.jar
java -Djava.library.path="M:\Java\SE\LWJGL_Fullscreen\final\lib\native\windows\" -jar LWJGL_Fullscreen.jar
java -jar LWJGL_Fullscreen.jar -Djava.library.path="M:\Java\SE\LWJGL_Fullscreen\final\lib\native\windows\"
```

unfortunately these didn't work either. I got the same output as before.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045608/proper-usage-of-java-d-command-line-parameters might help. Just try putting the -D before the -jar

Comment: doesn't help... if i put the `-D` between the `-jar` and the file name java just stops working.

Comment: That is quite possible, if you put the -Djava.library... part between -jar and the filename, java will think the jar to be executed is -Djava.lib... instead of the file. Did you try putting the whole -Djava.lib.. thing before the -jar? The command would be  `java -Djava.library.path="M:\Java\SE\LWJGL_Fullscreen\final\lib\native\windows\" -jar=LWJGL_Fullscreen.jar`

Comment: yes. same result as in the question.

Comment: It might also be something totally different, an incompatibility of libraries or some missing dependency. Hope that this time it is helpful :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2516890/error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm

Comment: ok.. it won't work with 64bit java... that's kind of strange...